# Renumbering cells after moving them

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a bunch of cells, all of which have a label that displays its row. When I move cells in the table, I would like the cells to renumber according to their new rows. After trying the code below, the numbers are all off. How would I fix this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{



    for (int section = 0; section < [tableView numberOfSections]; section++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++) {
            NSIndexPath* cellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
            CustomCell* cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:cellPath];

            NSString *rowString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.", row + 1];
            cell.periodLabel.text = rowString1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let Model-View-Controller be your friend.

Instead of thinking "renumber the cells", think "renumber the objects". Use a Model object (say `MyNumberedRow`) to represent the data in the cell. When the cell moves, retrieve that cell's `MyNumberedRow` instance, update that.

Even if you have hundreds of items in your logical table, you'll only see a few of those realized as `CustomCell` instances. If it's not on screen, the cell won't exist.

Side note: use `NSInteger`, not `int`. It avoids type problems in 32/64 bit conversions. It's also the return type of `-numberOfSections`.